# Exit traffic code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this code for exit traffic

```
<script type=”text/javascript” language=”javascript”>
    function areYouSure() {
    areYouReallySure = true;
    location.href=”http://example.com”
    return “WAIT! Maybe you’d like to try ShamWow instead?\r\nOrder now and we’ll have Chuck Norris personally deliver it!”;

}
window.onbeforeunload = areYouSure;
</script>
```

The code is simply never called.

This is a demo http://provendate.com/testpop.php

Why?

Comment: Do you use ” or ", there is a difference

Comment: It'll work once you replace the fancy quotes with `"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a confirmation when someone navigates away from the page, all you have to do is:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "I'm a really annoying message, please stay !";
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/es2uT/1/) is a fiddle